# Value attribute of list tag truncating anything above 2147483647 in IE

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The value attribute takes maximum of 2147483647, if it is beyond that it will reset it to 2147483647 in IE.Any solution that can help to overcome this problem.

```
<ol>
  <li value =2147483648>Test</li>
</ol>
```

will come as 
83647 test
and if you inspect element it will come as 2147483647 instead of 2147483648

Comment: `2147483647`seems to be the maximum length of a `<ol>`, Chrome goes in overflow too(2147483648 will be shown as 1). Did you really need so many elements?

Comment: I don't have so many elements but i have elements those are created dynamically with unique number and this number needs to be assigned to value attribute.

Comment: May I suggest to create a custom placeholder for the listing in you case?

Comment: @FeMachine can you explain this custom placeholder

Comment: It likely has to do with 2,147,483,647 being the maximum number that can be represented with a 32-bit signed integer. [z-index has the same limitation](http://softwareas.com/whats-the-maximum-z-index/). In this case, there is no way to force it to use a higher number, since it can't store that higher number. You'll need to find some other way around it.

Answer (score 0):

that's an alternative, with no number limitations

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
 <li>
 <span class="custom-placeholder">12398712398712398712.</span>
   asd
 </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This will not work the correct solution will be creating custom attribute but thanks for help